# C run external program get error

Tags: c, system

In my `C` code I want to run an external program.
For this I use `system()` function like this example:

```
system("/bin/myprog");
```

But I want to detect if my external program have error or not exit correctly.
How can I get the error?

Comment: Look at the return code from `system()`

Comment: use popen, so you can read output message. "http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipe-to-a-Subprocess.html"

Comment: i real manual, but i want to get error message, not only check if i have error like this code 
 if (!(ret = system("mycommand"))) {}

Comment: As @ShihabPullissery say, use popen(). With popen you will be able to read the output of your program directly in your "Parent" program: https://linux.die.net/man/3/popen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the error message then you need to trap the `stderr` from the external program. Note that `popen` traps `stdout`, so you need to redirect using the shell construct `2>&1` (fortunately `popen` also runs a shell).  For example:

```
#define BUFF_SIZE 1024

int main()
{
    char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];

    FILE *p = popen("/bin/myprog 2>&1", "r");

    while (fgets(buffer, BUFF_SIZE, p))
        printf("Recieved: %s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:  To ignore `stdout` messages and only get `stderr` messages then use:

```
FILE *p = popen("/bin/myprog 2>&1 1>/dev/null", "r");
```

Comment: thank you for your code but it's not work, if i run a bash script like this :
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
echo $((2 / 0))

your code print my hello message

Comment: When I ran that I got the hello message and the error message.  So to be clear, do you **only** want the error message?

Comment: OK, what do you want to do with the `stdout` text?  Should it be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

use popen, so you can read output message. [popen man3](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

Comment: `popen` only traps `stdout` and the OP wants to read error messages.

Comment: `popen` return an open stream from where you can read the output of `myprog` no matter its error message or other data. If Fails returns `returns` NULL and set `errno`

Comment: From `man popen`:  "*reading from the stream reads the command's
       standard output*".  So no, it won't read `stderr` unless you do a `dup2`, or the shell equivalent.  The `errno` only indicates if the shell ran the command, not if the command was successful.  See also `system(3)`.